# How to add a transparent scrollbar in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have been adding the overflow-Y: scroll to materialize collections since I set the fixed wrapper height. However, I have been searching to make the scrollbars transparent. I have found questions and answers about adding WebKit. But it throws errors and I do know those are not addable in React. I have tried with external CSS with a specific ID. But it still doesn't work. The contents are really ugly to my eyes with the scrollbar.

```
#no-scroll1::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 0px;  
   background: transparent; 
}
```

Below is the react.

```
<div
          id="no-scroll1"
          className="col s2 z-depth-2 grey lighten-5 no-scroll"
          style={{ height: "55em", overflowY: "scroll"}}
    >
```

Note - I am using Chrome and developing with React, Babel CDNs.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you tried adding `webkit` scrollbars?

Comment: I just edited @Agney

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
#no-scroll1::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: auto;
}
#no-scroll1::-webkit-scrollbar-track, #no-scroll1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Just making background trransparent for scrollbar track and thumb. Don't need to use `width: 0`

Comment: Using 'background: transparent' sets the track to a white background.

Answer (score 0):

Check the snippet and the stackblitz react implementation, [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-n1ukzm).

```css
#no-scroll1::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 0px;
 background: transparent;
}
#no-scroll1{
border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="no-scroll1" class="col s2 z-depth-2 grey lighten-5 no-scroll" style="height: 10em; width:200px; overflow-y: scroll">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: If you are using `width: 0px`. What is the case for using `background: transparent` ?

Comment: @NipunJain I am not a expert in css,  I just recreated his css properties in both stackblitz and the snippet :)

Answer (score 0):

Default:

[image]

After:

[image]

```
#no-scroll1 {
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #no-scroll1:hover {
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        #no-scroll1::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 8px;
            height: 16px;
        }

        #no-scroll1::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            display: none;
        }

        #no-scroll1::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        #no-scroll1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
        }

<div id="no-scroll1" className="col s2 z-depth-2 grey lighten-5 no-scroll"
        style="border:solid 1px #000;height:5em;width:150px; ">

        test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
        test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />

    </div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.